# Bind Hotkey to button click in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a div which has an `ng-click` event:

```
<div class="modalWindowClose" ng-click="closeSettings(user, users);"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
```

I want to click the element when the escape key is pressed, preferably within the HTML itself.  Something like this:

```
<div class="modalWindowClose" hotkey="{esc:'click this element'}" ng-click="closeSettings(user, users);"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
```

What is the best way to do something like that? I tried the Angular hotkeys by Chief Fancy Pants but it didn't let me click the specific element, only run a function.

Comment: I think custom directive could be used, could be quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments, you should probably write custom `hotkey` directive. I would design the simple one like this:

```
.directive('hotkey', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var config = scope.$eval(attrs.hotkey)
      angular.forEach(config, function(value, key) {
        angular.element(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode === Number(key)) {
            element.triggerHandler(value)  
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Then it would be used in HTML like this:

```
<div hotkey="{27: 'click'}" ng-click="closeSettings(user, users);">Close</div>
```

Where "27" is the key code (27 is ESC) and the value `click` corresponds to the action to trigger on this element.

Check out the usage and demo of it in action below.

```js
angular.module('demo', [])

.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.closeSettings = function() {
    console.log('closeSettings')
  }
})

.directive('hotkey', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var config = scope.$eval(attrs.hotkey)
      angular.forEach(config, function(value, key) {
        angular.element(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode === Number(key)) {
            element.triggerHandler(value)  
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <div class="modalWindowClose" hotkey="{27: 'click'}" ng-click="closeSettings(user, users);"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this allow you to pass parameters into the click function?

Comment: hotkey directive will simply invoke ngClick expression. So like in the demo I posted ESC key will trigger `closeSettings(user, users)` function with two parameters, user and users. The effect from ESC key is the same as clicking,

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-keypress directive and then check the keyEvent in your controller.

You can find more documentation here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress

```
<div ng-keypress="test(param1, $event)" ng-click="test(param1)></div>

$scope.test = function(param1, keyEvent) {
  if(keyEvent) {
    if(keyEvent.which === 23) { 
       // esc
    }
  } else {
       // click
  }

};
```

Comment: how do I fire a click on the element when the keypress happens?

Comment: why do you need to fire a click? why don't you just call a function when the keypress happens?

Comment: Because I need to pass parameters in and I want to only call the same function once

Comment: can't you get this parameters from the scope? See my modification